# PhantomJS execute javascript in <Body> tag

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, phantomjs, dynamic-html

I am trying to scrape the below mentioned URL and trying to extract the link in the  tag,using PhantomJS.
The link sends back javascript code which is executed on the browser to form the HTML inside the Body.
The problem is PhantomJS is not executing the Javascript and I am getting the unfinished HTML after executing my code.

Index.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
console.log('The default user agent is ' + page.settings.userAgent);
page.settings.userAgent = 'SpecialAgent';
page.open('http://videohost.site/play/A11QStEaNdVZfvV/', function(status) {
  if (status !== 'success') {
    console.log('Unable to access network');
  } else {
    var html = page.evaluate(function() {
      return document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].innerHTML;
    });
    console.log(html);
  }
  phantom.exit();
});
```

I execute it using phantomjs index.js in the console t check the HTML.
Any help regarding how would the script inside the  would be executed would be much appreciated.

Update:
works with NightMareJS as according to Vaviloff's suggestion.

```
app.get('/scrape', function (req, res) {

  //All the web scraping magic will happen here
  console.log('Scrape')
  url = 'http://videohost.site/play/A11QStEaNdVZfvV/'
  nightmare
    .goto(url)
    .evaluate(function(){

        return document.body.innerHTML; //pass all of the html as text
    })
    .end()   
    .then(function (document) {
      console.log(document)
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
      console.error('Search failed:', error);
    })

  res.send('Woohoo')

})
app.listen('8081')

console.log('Magic happens on port 8081');

exports = module.exports = app;
```

Comment: It's likely because PhantomJS doesn't support Flash and <video> now.

Comment: Thanks..So what are the other alternatives

Comment: Can you use SlimerJS? Its syntax is identical to PhantomJS. An even better variant would be NightmareJS, although you'd have to rewrite the script.

Comment: Okay thanks , I will try them out and post my findings

Comment: Yes it works with NightMareJS, as it is able to load the entire HTML.Thanks for your help.